# Playing getExternalFilesDir mp3 using exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am fairly new to exoplayer and I having some difficulties playing audio files (specifically mp3) via external files directory in android.

```
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(this)
        trackSelector.setParameters(
            trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setMaxVideoSizeSd()
        )
        val player : SimpleExoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).build()


        videoView.player = player
        // Create a data source factory.
        val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this)
        // Create a progressive media source pointing to a stream uri.
        val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.fromFile(getExternalFilesDir("app_tracks/helloaudio.mp3"))))

        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        player.playWhenReady = true
        player.seekTo(0, 0)
        player.prepare()
```

And it gave me an error - Source error

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:554)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.app.android/files/app_tracks/helloaudio.mp3: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:97)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:193)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1013)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mindfi.app2.android/files/app_tracks/helloaudio.mp3: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

I check the audio file whether is exists using isExist method, and it return true to me.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the android version? You getting file not found exception< looks like you trying to get your file wrong way or it is not exist. If you are using android 8+ you suppose to use FileProvider to get Uri, not Uri.fromFile()
code example:

```
final Uri uri = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) ?
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, packageName + ".provider", file) : Uri.fromFile(file);
```

in manifest:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.yourpackage.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

xml/file_paths (in res folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: I am using android 8+. Ah I see, do you have an example? Really appreciated much.

Comment: Thank you! Will give a try and let you know!

Comment: Thanks Alex. I got confused for the method - getExternalFilesDir. That method is just getting the directory folder, and I'm doing it wrong from the start. Your answer is the correct way of getting the file from the external storage. Thanks again!